# Did Rama stop the aerial car at Nandigrama itself to meet Bharata?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita

I have a confusion on whether Rama stopped the Pushpaka Vimana at Nandigrama itself to meet Bharata. If yes, then how Rama and Sita reached Ayodhya from Nandigrama?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `"Did Rama stop the aerial car at Nandigrama itself to meet Bharata?"`

#### **YES**

Rama stopped the Pushpaka Vimana at Nandigrama itself to meet Bharata.

I'm directly quoting from the [Summary of the ValmikiRamayana](http://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/yuddha/sarga127/yuddha_127_frame.htm) Page:

> #### Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa:Book VI : Yuddha Kanda, Chapter [Sarga] 127,
>
> ##### Verses 1 - 24
>
> > **Bharata, after hearing the good news from Hanuma about the arrival of
> > Rama, calls Shatrughna and commands him to make appropriate
> > arrangements for the reception of Rama in the City of Ayodhya. Bharata
> > departs with all others, for Nandigrama to receive Rama. The aerial
> > car lands at Nandigrama.** Bharata welcomes Rama and others, by
> > embracing them and by greeting them joyously. Rama too offers his
> > salutations to all his mothers, who come to receive him. Then, Bharata
> > brings Rama's wooden sandals and places them below the feet of Rama.
> > Rama commands Pushpaka, the aerial car to return to Kubera, the lord
> > of riches to whom it originally belonged.

---

Further,

### `"If yes, then how Rama and Sita reached Ayodhya from Nandigrama?"`

They reached the palace seated on their royal Chariots.

> #### [Chapter [Sarga] 128](http://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/yuddha/sarga128/yuddha_128_frame.htm)
>
> > 27. The faultless Rama, mounting the excellent chariot, as Indra ascended the chariot yoked to green-coloured horses, sallied forth to the city.
>
> > 28. Bharata took up the reins. Shatrughna held the parasol on Rama's head. Lakshmana winnowed a fan. Vibhishana, the king of demons standing nearby, held a white fan, shining brilliantly like the moon.
>
> ...
>
> > 34. Then, the people of Ayodhya saw Rama, the chariot warrior, having a beautiful form, arriving on a chariot, with attendants walking in front.